# Установка flask

Tags: python, flask, pip

Не подскажите, как можно установить flask через PowerShell на Windows 10? Через "pip install flask" 
и
  "easy_install flask" не работает, указаывая на то, что это не распознано как имя командлета, функции, файла сценария или выполняемой программы.

Comment: Пропиши в PATH путь до pip

Comment: `python.exe -m pip install flask`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В питоновских скриптах с версии 3.4 менеджер пакетов pip включен автоматически. Но, чтобы обращаться к нему напрямую без прописывания каждый раз пути до директории, в которой лежит файл pip.exe вам нужно добавить его в область видимости системы. Загуглите, как добавить переменную в path. Для одноразовой установки пакета можно прописать и полный путь до файла pip.exe и потом в этой же строке передать ему необходимые команды типа install flask.

Если pip не добавлен в среду path(а сделать это очень просто, и если вы собираетесь устанавливать еще какие-либо python пакеты вам будет очень неудобно писать каждый раз путь до файла pip.exe), то вы при обращении к pip должны прописать полный путь до него. --> Нажмите на свойства вашего python интерпретатора, скопируйте путь до /python.exe Должно получиться что-то такое

```
C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\
```

Теперь допишите в конец - Scripts\pip.exe

В итоге должно получиться

```
C:\Users\Фёдор\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\pip.exe
```

С учетом вашего имени пользователя и версии python.

А теперь вместо pip пишите весь путь до pip. Команда pip install flask должна быть такой

```
C:\Users\Фёдор\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\pip.exe install flask
```

Опять же с учетом вашего имени пользователя и версии python.

---

Чтобы использовать просто pip, в переменную окружения path нужно добавить два пути(опять, как вы догадались, с учетом вашего имени пользователя и версии python.)

```
C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\
C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts
```